# How to convert json stored in DB into csv using meteor

Tags: csv, meteor

I want to download a CSV file generated from a database (nodeDB) which has the following entries.
These entries should act as headers only.

```
{    

    "META": {

        "TEMPLATE_NAME": "B", 

        "TEMPLATE_GROUP": "Product", 
        "KEYWORDS": [
            "cc"
        ], 

        "TEMPLATE_SUBGROUP": ""
    }, 
    "VARIENTS": [
        {
            "NAME": "Brand", 
            "DATATYPE": "Text",
        }

    ]
}
```

I have written the following code:

HTML:

```
<template name="templateForCSV">
    <a href="{{pathFor 'csv'}}" target="_blank">Download the CSV</a>
</template>
```

JS:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    //CSV Download
    var DataCursor=nodeDB.find({});
    if (DataCursor.count() === 0) {
      for(var i=1; i<=DataCursor.length; i++) {
        //Example for Now, has to be changed
        nodeDB.insert({Brand: "Brand" + i,Price: "Price" + i, Description:"Description" + i});
      }
    }
  });
 }

Router.route('/csv', {
  where: 'server',
  action: function () {
    var filename = 'data.csv';
    var fileData = "";

    var headers = {
      'Content-type': 'text/csv',
      'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename
    };
    var records = nodeDB.find();
    // This is the main problem. build a CSV string. Oversimplified. You'd have to escape quotes and commas.
    records.forEach(function(rec) {
      fileData += rec.META + "," + rec.VARIENTS + "," +  "\r\n";
    });
    this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
    return this.response.end(fileData);
  }
});
```

The CSV file is downloaded but it is blank. What's happening?

Comment: You have formatting issues, and did you actually write `dataCursor.length`?

Comment: yes, What are the issues, please explain

Comment: If you try to fetch all the data (`console.log(nodeDB.find().fetch());` in a `meteor shell` for example) is there any data at all?

Comment: yes there is...that is what is shown in the question also..

Comment: @garmina Are you opposed to using a package that does most of this for you?

Comment: To me your question is a little confusing. In your first snippet you're showing us an entry how it should look but then you are inserting an example entry which looks totally different. When adding data to `fileData` you are again using the property names from your first snippet which don't exist in your example (and therefore maybe also not in your DB). Also it's not totally clear if the problem is with creating the file (does it work when you fill a fix string in `fileData`?) or with your collection (debug `records` and `rec`)... It would be nice if you could clarify that and break it down.

Answer (score 0):

First, assume that your `nodeDB` works fine. Your problem could be that the route is not defined for `/csv`, so just try the below to test.

```
<template name="templateForCSV">
    <a href="/csv" target="_blank">Download the CSV</a>
</template>
```

If that still turns up blank, I would guess that your `nodeDB` is blank, so try the below to test.

```
Router.route('/csv', function () {
    var filename = 'data.csv';
    var fileData = "hello, world";

    var headers = {
      'Content-type': 'text/csv',
      'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename
    };

    this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
    this.response.end(fileData);
  }, {where: "server"});
```

The CSV file with "hello, world" should be downloaded. Note that I changed the syntax a bit on the above to what I use.

Try this and let us know if it works.