# How to create multiple csvs in the Meteor App

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor

I want to create multiple csvs each for the document present in the MongoDb Collection. Each document is nothing but a JSON file.

The JSON consists of two parts: META DATA and Variables.

I am sharing the Router Code, please suggest changes. This is not handling multiple csvs.

```
Router.route('/csv', {
    where: 'server',
    action: function () {
        //change the name of the file to the Template Name on the click on the selected Template. Currently using the name as data.csv

        var filename = 'data.csv';
        var fileData = "";

        var headers = {
            'Content-type': 'text/csv',
            'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename
        };
        var records = nodeDB.find();

        records.forEach(function(rec) {
            fileData += rec.META + "," + rec.VARIENTS  + "\r\n";
        });
        this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
        return this.response.end(fileData);
    }
});
```

I am showing multiple JSONs on the Table. On the click of the row, the respective CSV has to be downloaded.We do not require a CSV zip file.

Comment: This is the second time you've asked the question (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613182/how-to-convert-json-stored-in-db-into-csv-using-meteor). I looked at the first too, but its difficult to tell what you're asking. Note, you can't download two files with one request without making a zip file. What is wrong with the code above? It looks like it makes a csv file

Comment: even the above question is not answered by anyone, so this link doesnt help anyway

Answer (score 1):

You should try this package [json2csv](https://github.com/axwaxw/json2csv)

and go through explanation of json2csv , this package also downloading data from json to csv ,

and for multiple csv first you need zip all files and then you  can download zip file

this link will also help [nodejs package](http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/)

Comment: I dont want to use zip file, any way to download separately?

Comment: then use first  link to download as a csv no need to zip it